# Jenkins Python параметризованная сборка

Tags: python, jenkins

Есть автотесты, написанные на Python. Там используются переменные, переданные через консоль.

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

Не подскажите, как при помощи Jenkins'a передать туда значение?
При использовании параметризованной сборки (передаю string env), тесты не выполняются.

Comment: Если автотесты обрабатывают аргументы, а не переменные окружения, то передавать надо именно аргументы, а не переменные окружения.

Comment: Вы тесты как запускаете сейчас, какой командой?

Comment: py.test <название теста>

Comment: @Сергей а когда руками запускаете, как передаете переменные?